# NUnit - NullReferenceException while authenticating with Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, nunit, membership-provider

I am trying to test authentication in an unit test:

```
 // code in Unit Test method
 var loginModel = new LoginModel();
 loginModel.UserName = "userhere";
 loginModel.Password = "passhere";
 loginModel.RememberMe = false;
 var accountController = CreateAccountController();
 accountController.Login(loginModel, ""); 

protected static AccountController CreateAccountController()
{
        var routes = new RouteCollection();
        var controller = new AccountController();
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(HttpContextBaseMock.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
        controller.Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(HttpContextBaseMock.Object, new RouteData()), routes);
        return controller;
}
```

But I am getting a NullReferenceException when WebSecurity.Login method is called. It seems the error is down membership provider when SetAuthCookie is called.

Any idea how to fix this?

Should I try to mock this method?

Comment: Where is WebSecurity called, I can't see it in your code?

Comment: it is in AccountController.Login(). Nothing special there, just a simple call WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password)

Comment: So it sounds like WebSecurity is null.  You need to make sure that it's set.

Comment: The error itself is in WebSecurity.Login() => FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()

Comment: here it is the code in WebSecurity.Login (taken with DotPeek):       public static bool Login(string userName, string password, bool persistCookie = false)
    {
      WebSecurity.VerifyProvider();
      bool flag = Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password);
      if (flag)
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, persistCookie);
      return flag;
    }

Comment: More than this, System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl is not null.